# Golang static identifier resolution

Tags: go, static-analysis

I'm attempting to do some static analysis on function calls in a Go project using the `go/parse`, `go/token` and `go/ast` modules, but I can't figure out how to determine the type of a given `ast.Ident` object.

For instance if parse something like this:

```
textToContain := bytes.NewBuffer([]byte{})
// lots of other code
text := textToContain.String() // <- I care about this function call
```

(this is parsed from here: [file](https://github.com/EricChiang/pup/blob/69d82fdf3370dea7213706b9ca30487d17f78c6d/selector.go#L571))

EDIT: It took a lot of code to parse this so I didn't post it here, but you can find it as a gist at: https://gist.github.com/EricChiang/6735340c5fa3d2de2b73

I get the following code printed using the [`ast.Print`](http://golang.org/pkg/go/ast/#Print) function

```
 0  *ast.CallExpr {
 1  .  Fun: *ast.SelectorExpr {
 2  .  .  X: *ast.Ident {
 4  .  .  .  Name: "textToContain"
 5  .  .  .  Obj: *ast.Object {
 6  .  .  .  .  Kind: var
 7  .  .  .  .  Name: "textToContain"
 8  .  .  .  .  Decl: *ast.AssignStmt {
 9  .  .  .  .  .  Lhs: []ast.Expr (len = 1) {
10  .  .  .  .  .  .  0: *ast.Ident {
12  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  Name: "textToContain"
13  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  Obj: *(obj @ 5)
14  .  .  .  .  .  .  }
15  .  .  .  .  .  }
17  .  .  .  .  .  Tok: :=
18  .  .  .  .  .  Rhs: []ast.Expr (len = 1) {
19  .  .  .  .  .  .  0: *ast.CallExpr {
20  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  Fun: *ast.SelectorExpr {
21  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  X: *ast.Ident {
23  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  Name: "bytes"
24  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  }
25  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  Sel: *ast.Ident {
27  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  Name: "NewBuffer"
28  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  }
29  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  }
31  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  Args: []ast.Expr (len = 1) {
32  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  0: *ast.CompositeLit {
33  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  Type: *ast.ArrayType {
35  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  Elt: *ast.Ident {
37  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  Name: "byte"
38  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  }
39  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  }
42  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  }
43  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  }
44  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  Ellipsis: -
46  .  .  .  .  .  .  }
47  .  .  .  .  .  }
48  .  .  .  .  }
49  .  .  .  }
50  .  .  }
51  .  .  Sel: *ast.Ident {
53  .  .  .  Name: "String"
54  .  .  }
55  .  }
57  .  Ellipsis: -
59  }
```

But I can't see where I could infer the type of `textToContain`

I know a bunch of tools that can do this, for instance [this example](http://golang.org/lib/godoc/analysis/help.html#tmp_2) from the go blog, but I think I'm going in the wrong direction.

Comment: hard to figure out without some sample code.

Comment: @fabrizioM took a lot of code to get here so I refrained from putting it in. you can find a gist here https://gist.github.com/EricChiang/6735340c5fa3d2de2b73

Answer (score 6):

3of3 is right; you need the type checker, which is `golang.org/x/tools/go/types`.  In general, the type of an expression depends on type information for the transitive closure of import dependencies, so you will probably want to use the `golang.org/x/tools/go/loader` package (which I maintain), which takes care of many challenging details for you.  Its `stdlib_test.go` may be a useful starting point.

Once you've identified the expression of interest, you can find its type in one of the mappings within the `types.Info` structure for the AST's package.

In this case, the expression is a referring identifier (`*ast.Ident`) so look in the `Uses` mapping to find the `types.Object` (named entity) to which it refers---a local variable (`*types.Var`) in this case.  For expressions other than identifiers, the `Types` mapping will tell you its type.