# Determine whether dynamically specified Go variable has specific type

Tags: go

I'm writing a command line application where a user specifies 1) a directory containing Go files, 2) the name of a variable that should be a `http.Handler`, e.g.

```
go run cli.go /path/to/a/go/library MyCustomHandler
```

I'm trying to

- parse the files
- find the variable with the given name
- verify that it's a `http.Handler`

I can do the first two no problem - I call `parser.ParseDir`, then get the package I want as an `*ast.Package`, then loop over it like this:

```
func findHttpHandler(pkg *ast.Package, handlerName string) (*ast.FuncDecl, error) {
    for _, file := range pkg.Files {
        for _, decl := range file.Decls {
            gd, ok := decl.(*ast.GenDecl)
            if !ok || gd.Tok != token.VAR {
                continue
            }
            if len(gd.Specs) != 1 {
                continue
            }
            spec0 := gd.Specs[0]
            vs, ok := spec0.(*ast.ValueSpec)
            if !ok {
                continue
            }
            if len(vs.Names) != 1 {
                continue
            }
            ident := vs.Names[0]
            if ident.Name != handlerName {
                continue
            }
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is at this point the `ValueSpec.Type` is nil, and there doesn't appear to be any way to figure out whether this is a `http.Handler` or not.

The `go/types` package has more tools for checking types, but it also looks like you need to do a lot more setup work to get this, essentially parsing and type checking the whole program. Am I going to need to go down this path, or is there an easier way, just using the `ast` package, or using `go build` somehow?

Comment: Hi Kevin ! :) It looks close to this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27976493/golang-static-identifier-resolution
I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

did some trace and find the way, hoping help

https://play.golang.org/p/f4XF8K_FbL

```
package main

import (
    "go/parser"
    "go/token"
    "os"
    "go/ast"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    //"reflect"
)

func MyCustomHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r* http.Request){

}

func findHttpHandler(pkg *ast.Package, handlerName string) (*ast.FuncDecl, error) {
    for _, file := range pkg.Files {
        for _, decl := range file.Decls {
            fd, ok := decl.(*ast.FuncDecl)
            if !ok || fd == nil{
                continue
            }
            if fd.Name.Name != handlerName{
                continue
            }
            if len(fd.Type.Params.List) == 2 {
                p1 := fd.Type.Params.List[0]
                p2 := fd.Type.Params.List[1]

                exp, ok := p1.Type.(*ast.SelectorExpr)
                if !ok{
                    break;
                }
                ident, ok := exp.X.(*ast.Ident)
                if !ok{
                    break
                }
                if ident.Name!="http" || exp.Sel.Name != "ResponseWriter"{
                    break;
                }

                exp2, ok := p2.Type.(*ast.StarExpr)
                if !ok{
                    break;
                }
                exp = exp2.X.(*ast.SelectorExpr)
                ident, ok = exp.X.(*ast.Ident)
                if !ok{
                    break
                }
                if ident.Name!="http" || exp.Sel.Name != "Request"{
                    break;
                }
                return fd, nil
            }
        }
    }
    return nil, nil
}

func main() {
    fs := token.NewFileSet()
    pkgs, err := parser.ParseDir(fs, os.Args[1], nil, parser.Trace)
    if err != nil{
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    for _,pkg:=range pkgs{
        d, _ := findHttpHandler(pkg, "MyCustomHandler");
        log.Println(d)
    }
}
```