# Finding the type of a variable through static analysis?

Tags: go, types, static-analysis

How can I determine the type of a variable through static analysis?

Suppose I have the following code:

```
func doSomething(x interface{}) {}

func main() {
  p := Person()
  doSomething(p)
}
```

And I want to analyze `doSomething(person)`, is it possible to get the type of Person through static analysis?

What if there were multiple levels of assignment?

```
p1 := Person()
p2 := p1
doSomething(p2)
```

or

```
parent := Parent()
p := Parent.Child() // type Person
doSomething(p)
```

The use case is that I have a generic function that is commonly used throughout the (very large) codebase, and would like to introduce a new type safe version of this function. To do this, I hope to automatically determine the "type" of the function and refactor it accordingly:

```
// old
DB.InsertRow(person)

// new
Person.InsertRow(person)
```

Comment: If `Person()` returns a concrete type then, yes it is possible to get the type of `p1`, `p2`, `parent`, and `p` (assuming `Parent.Child()` also returns a concrete type). However if the function returns an interface whose dynamic type is decided based on some parameters that the program acquires at runtime (e.g. user input, info from a database, or the internet, etc.), then static analysis will be insufficient to get the type.

Comment: If putting this up for a bounty - it may be helpful to add more clarity on your larger goal here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the advice from [Golang static identifier resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27976493/golang-static-identifier-resolution) to use `golang.org/x/tools/go/types`, I found that this was pretty straight forward to do with the `golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis` package, which has the types info [available alongside the parsed ast](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis#Pass.TypesInfo).

This was my solution:

```
package rewriter

import (
    "go/ast"

    "golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis"

    "golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/passes/inspect"

    "golang.org/x/tools/go/ast/inspector"
)

func run(pass *analysis.Pass) (interface{}, error) {
    inspect := pass.ResultOf[inspect.Analyzer].(*inspector.Inspector)

    nodeFilter := []ast.Node{
        (*ast.CallExpr)(nil),
    }

    inspect.Nodes(nodeFilter, func(node ast.Node, push bool) bool {
        callExpr, ok := node.(*ast.CallExpr)
        if !ok {
            return true
        }

        funcExpr, ok := callExpr.Fun.(*ast.SelectorExpr)
        if !ok {
            return true
        }

        // check method name
        if funcExpr.Sel.Name != "doSomething" {
            return true
        }

        for _, arg := range callExpr.Args {
            // lookup type of the arg
            argType := pass.TypesInfo.Types[arg].Type
            if argType.String() == "*rewriter.Person" {
                // do whatever you want here
            }
        }
        return false
    })
    return nil, nil
}
```

One can augment this to look at the receiver of the method and add refactoring logic as needed (using [analysis.Diagnostic](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis#Diagnostic)).

Answer (score 1):

Finding the type of an expression through static analysis is non-trivial, and sometimes not possible, for details see [Golang static identifier resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27976493/golang-static-identifier-resolution).

> The use case is that I have a generic function that is commonly used throughout the (very large) codebase, and would like to introduce a new type safe version of this function. To do this, I hope to automatically determine the "type" of the function and refactor it accordingly:
>
> ```
> // old
> DB.InsertRow(person)
>
> // new
> Person.InsertRow(person)
> ```

Just for refactoring purposes, I don't think it is worth the hassle to implement it.

What you may do is change the signature of `DB.InsertRow()` temporarily to accept only a specific type such as `int` or your custom type you're sure is not used anywhere (e.g. `type tempFoo struct{}`).

To what end? Doing so, the compiler will do the hard work for you. You will see error messages showing exactly the types your codebase is trying to pass to `DB.InsertRow()`, so I'd say mission accomplished.

For example this code compiles:

```
func doSomething(x interface{}) {}

func main() {
    doSomething(image.Pt(1, 2))
    doSomething("abc")
    doSomething(image.Rect) // image.Rect is a function which we don't call,
                            // so we're passing a value of a function type here
}
```

If we change `doSomething()`:

```
func doSomething(x int) {}
```

We get the types we're seeking for from the compiler:

> ./prog.go:10:14: cannot use image.Pt(1, 2) (value of type **image.Point**) as type int in argument to doSomething
>
> ./prog.go:11:14: cannot use "abc" (untyped **string constant**) as int value in argument to doSomething
>
> ./prog.go:12:14: cannot use image.Rect (value of type **func(x0 int, y0 int, x1 int, y1 int) image.Rectangle)** as type int in argument to doSomething